# Convert simple text into html honoring newlines whitespaces and tabs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ckeditor4.x

Writing a method to convert simple text file into html so that it can be integrated inside ckeditor. However we are unable to convert whitespaces, tabs and new lines with any RoR gems

I have tried with

```
output_html = ActionController::Base.helpers.simple_format(contents)
output_html = output_html.gsub(/ (?= )/, '&nbsp;')
```

```
text_content = "firstline\nsecond   line \n\n\nthird line\t\taftertab"

output_html = "firstline<br/>second&nbsp;&nbsp;line<br/><br/><br/>third<br/>line&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;aftertab"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just use `String.gsub` for this:

```
text_content = "firstline\nsecond   line \n\n\nthird line\t\taftertab"

text_content.gsub(/\s/, "\n" => "<br/>", "\t" => "&nbsp;&nbsp;", " " => "&nbsp;")
# => "firstline<br/>second&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;line&nbsp;<br/><br/><br/>third&nbsp;line&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;aftertab"
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response. The proposed code works fine. However is there any libraries or gems available that can do the same thing? For example to convert wiki or .md files there is something like GitHub::Markup.render or Redcarpet::Markdown etc. Similar to that do we have any existing text2html libs to use instead ?

Comment: @Mendy, I don't remember gems that convert such strings. Redcarpet convert markdown strings.

Comment: You could also use `&emsp;` in place of the tab character which is more representational of a tab in my opinion as it essentially represents `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;`

Comment: @engineersmnky, good idea, I think so. But the OP wanted two whitespaces.